# AutoHotKey: PixelSearch only when key is pressed

Tags: colors, autohotkey

I have a simple color clicker code.

```
    ~C:: 
    Loop
    {
        PixelSearch, Px, Py, 300, 300, 300, 300, 0x91595c, 5, Fast
       if errorlevel
       {
          sleep 20
          return
       }
       else
       {
        Send, {LButton Down}
        Sleep, 250
        Send, {LButton Up}
        Sleep, 500
       } 
    }
    return
```

When pressing a C, its find a right color and send a click.
But i tired to make it work ONLY when C is pressed and finish color search when C is not pressed.

**What have you already tried?**
I tried to make this work with:

```
while  KeyIsDown := GetKeyState("c", "P")
```

or

```
if  KeyIsDown := GetKeyState("c")
```

But it just come to infinite loop or doesnt work.
Can you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Find a solution:**

```
 $F2:: 
    Loop
    {
        PixelSearch, Px, Py, 300, 300, 300, 300, 0x91595c, 5, Fast
       if errorlevel
       {
          sleep 20
          return
       }
       else
        if GetKeyState("C","p") 
       {
        Send, {LButton Down}
        Sleep, 250
        Send, {LButton Up}
        Sleep, 500
       } 
    }
    return
```

Glad to see if you have a better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to keep the looping going until you release <kbd>C</kbd>. If so, you shouldn't `return` inside the loop, for that will stop it.

```
$F2:: 
Loop
{
    PixelSearch, Px, Py, 300, 300, 300, 300, 0x91595c, 5, Fast
   if errorlevel
   {
      sleep 20
   }
   else
    if GetKeyState("C","p") 
   {
    Send, {LButton Down}
    Sleep, 250
    Send, {LButton Up}
    Sleep, 500
   } 
   else
     break ; C was released: exit the loop, thus exit the thread
}
return
```

Also, you can keep `~C` as the hotkey, and if you really only want to "click", there is no need for a complicated `{LButton down}` etc.

Suggested code (also more compact):

```
~c::
    while(getKeyState("C","P)) {
        PixelSearch, Px, Py, 300, 300, 300, 300, 0x91595c, 5, Fast
        if( ! errorLevel ) {
            click
            sleep, 750
        } else {
            sleep 20
        }
    }
return
```